# Exception when installing Tweepy on OS X Terminal

Tags: python, exception, tweepy

I've browsed around but couldn't find anyone else getting this error. I'm trying to make a TwitterBot but I am unable to install tweepy with the following command:

```
pip install tweepy
```

I've tried using sudo/su and a few other methods but this exception always pops up:

```
pip install tweepy
Collecting tweepy
  Downloading tweepy-3.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.4.3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tweepy)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.4.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tweepy)
Collecting six>=1.7.3 (from tweepy)
  Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=0.6.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.4.1->tweepy)
Installing collected packages: six, tweepy
  Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling six-1.4.1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-ACL5B3-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Comment: Are you able to install any other modules? It looks like you need to run pip via `sudo`.

Comment: @Kogden, Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is linked to `six` package. 
Try to install tweepy running this command:

```
sudo pip install tweepy --ignore-installed six
```

or

```
pip install --ignore-installed six
```

You can find the `six issue` [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3165).

Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is for non root users.
Try,

```
sudo pip install tweepy
```